# PS3 won't stay connected to 2Wire AT&T DSL modem

Tags: ps3

I have a PS3 with working WiFi. I have connected to several other wireless networks in the past. I now am trying to connect to my 2Wire modem which shows 40% connectivity. Once I connect (if it even allows me), it almost always drops the connection within a minute or two.

I have a laptop I connect to from the same spot as my PS3 wirelessly and it not only stays connected but Speedtest.net gives it 5MB/s down and ~.70MB/s up.

I have also tried 'bridging' the connection from my laptop to my PS3 through an Ethernet cable but that does not work at all.

Has anybody else ever had this issue?

Comment: Have you checked your router's wireless channel with respect to other wireless routers in your area? Using an "un-crouded" channel may give a more stable connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not to familiar with how the 2wire AT&T DSL home network is setup. But if its anything like any other normal home network setup then it could be issues with your NAT type:

```
Type 1 - Connected directly to the internet (no router/firewall). Should have no issues.
Type 2 - Connected through a router properly. Should have no issues.
Type 3 - Connected through a router without open ports or DMZ setup for PS3. Everything should function properly, but you may have connection, voice chat or other issues.
```

An overkill, simple way to fix it would be to give your PS3 a static IP addres and put it in a DMZ on your wireless router/modem. This makes your PS3 completely unprotected by your router and can create some serious security problems if your not careful.

You can also open up the ports on your router.
TCP: 80, 443, 5223
UDP: 5223, 3478, 3479, 3658

More info and general directions [here](http://www.pregamelobby.com/ps3-ps2-psone-discussions/5618-how-get-type-2-open-nat-your-ps3.html)

Another thing to look into would be weird UPnP connection collisions. I saw similar network drops after a certain period of time online when running a media server on the same network.

More info and people with wireless network drops [here](http://www.avsforum.com/avs-vb/showthread.php?t=854920)

Comment: The OP's problem is about a dropping connection, not being unable to connect, which doesn't sound like a port-forwarding problem. Also, using DMZ is a pretty bad idea with regard to security.

Comment: Good point, I think its still possible to have a connection over a NAT Type 3 but things will be weird and can drop you quickly. Added more info about DMZ risk and also mentioned drops from UPnP issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the wireless receiver (Labeled Cisco_AP_ATT on your router) that AT&T uses  if you go wireless for your TV signal, uses port 443, which is the same port the PS3 uses. If you remove or change the Port on your AT&T router it will automatically put the Cisco_AP_ATT back after a few mins. If you DMZ your PS3 this will do nothing because the AT&T router will cut you off because of the conflict. You might be able to manualy port forward all ports that the PS3 uses but exclude the 443 port and that may solve your problem, but you may lose one of the PS3's functions i.e. voice... not sure.

Answer (score 0):

When I connect using the AT&T 4G Wifi hotspot  the connection initially was fast but the download speed slows down dramatically after 5GB of data. AT&T is likely throttling back the download speed since I am on an unlimited data plan.
I assume this is because the connection is NAT3.

Comment: Please don't double post.  You can edit your previous post if there is something you'd like to change.

Comment: @Joe - not really related to my issue regardless. It is publicly known AT&T throttles unlimited data plans at ~5 GB each month. It has nothing to do with the NAT3 connection